# mapStateToProps ownProps params are empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I'm new to React, React Router (v4) and Redux. I'm trying to access a URL parameter from `mapStateToProps(state, ownProps)` by accessing `ownProps.match.params.id` but the `params` array is always empty. I've used the debugger to inspect ownProps and the `id` parameter that should be passed isn't anywhere in `ownProps`.

Here is a snippet from my routes:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage} />
      <Route path='/course' component={ManageCoursePage} />
      <Route path='/course/:id' component={ManageCoursePage} />
      <Route path='/courses' component={CoursesPage} />
    </Switch>
```

Here is the relevant code from `ManageCoursePage.js`:

```
class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      course: Object.assign({}, props.course),
      errors: {},
    };
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  const courseId = ownProps.match.params.id;
  ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageCoursePage);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to flip the order of the following routes or set the `exact` property to the first route.

```
<Route path='/course' component={ManageCoursePage} />
<Route path='/course/:id' component={ManageCoursePage} />
```

`/course` matches before `/course/:id` thats why `ManageCoursePage` is called without the id param. 
if you only want to match `/course` in your first route and not `/course/123` you can set the [`exact` property](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool).